# How to achive prevent paste ,Ctrl+V ,Shift+Insert in InputText in Primefaces 3.0

Tags: primefaces

I have Email and Confirm email p:Inputtext, the Confirm Input Text user should type. Should be prevent paste(From browser Edit-->Paste) ,Ctrl+V ,Shift+Insert in p:InputText.

Please help me out this part.![Prevent paste][1]

Answer (score 0):

Use this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#txtInput').live("cut copy paste",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: this extension skips the onpaste restriction https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dont-fuck-with-paste/nkgllhigpcljnhoakjkgaieabnkmgdkb